# RecyclerView Add the items but replaces the intital items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Every time i add the new values from edit text the initial text disappears and recently added text will appears.Why this is happening? This is my adapter class.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder> {


private List<String> itemsName;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    itemsName = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, parent, false);
    return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsName.size();
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    onItemClickListener = listener;
}

public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener(){
    return onItemClickListener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
}

public void add(int location, String iName){
    itemsName.add(location, iName);
    notifyItemInserted(location);
}

public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private RecyclerViewAdapter parent;
    TextView textItemName;

    public ItemHolder(View itemView, RecyclerViewAdapter parent) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.parent = parent;
        textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    }

    public void setItemName(CharSequence name){
        textItemName.setText(name);
    }

    public CharSequence getItemName(){
        return textItemName.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
        }
    }
}}
```

This is Activity from where i send the Edit text field values on button click.

```
    btnsave =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String newName = txtHeading.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BuilderPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("key",newName);

            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(MyEditor
                    .this,"You added" +newName.toUpperCase()+ "in your view",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

This is the Builder.Activity where the items needs to be displayed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.builder_layout);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String nameList = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_builderxml);
    linearLayoutManager = new
            LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);

    myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);
    myRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
   myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(0,nameList);
```

The xml for Builder class is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_builderxml"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_builderxml"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:id="@+id/edittxtsurvey"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Your SurveyName"/>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom" >


    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="120dip">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"

            android:src="@drawable/arrowdown">

        </ImageView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1a237e"
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/plaintext"
                android:id="@+id/imgviewplaintext"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:onClick="oOnClick_PlainText"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/checkbox"
                android:id="@+id/imgviewcheckbox"
                android:onClick="OnClick_CheckBox"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgviewradiobutton"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgviewradiobutton"
                android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="21dp" />



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/radio"
                android:id="@+id/imgviewradiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:onClick="OnClick_RadioButton"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgviewtextbox"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgviewtextbox"
                android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="37dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/textbox"
                android:id="@+id/imgviewtextbox"
                android:onClick="onClick_textbox"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </SlidingDrawer>

   </RelativeLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: where you are calling the block below this "This is the Builder.Activity where the items needs to be displayed." in a method or onCreate?? Specify that.

Comment: ok i will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not what you think that items are not being replaced.But every time you click new instances are created so every-time you are seeing the new value or data.So you need to save the data you added somewhere.You have [DataStorageOptionsInAndroid](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). SO you can go through any of the options to save the data.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating and setting the adapter on onCreate. It will create a new instance always.

```
  myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

after this following manner should take place.

```
   myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(0,nameList);
   myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(1,nameList);
   myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(2,nameList);
   myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(3,nameList);
```

Try to change your logic. Don't pass the name list via string. Get all the names and send it to that activity and Get those values as String array or Get all names from that activity itself. Set that array to recycler view.

Comment: adding 0,1 this doesnot solves the problem.Can you share your logic how it can be implemented.I am a beginner to this.

Comment: How you are getting "nameList" for your application. Let me know where you are getting. I'll help you further.

Comment: ArrayList<String> nameList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key"); This i have called in Builder class

Comment: You misunderstood. How you are passing to his activity? In other activity how you are getting.

Comment: on click save button i have passed it as intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", nameList); and decleare ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(); in same activity

Comment: You are passing a StringExtra in the name of "key" and receiving it here. Instead of that Pass that whole ArrayList to this activity. Alter your Adapter and Pass the whole Array list. Then it will show the whole list. Only the lag is you are getting a single "key" value here. So when this activity launched, it will show that one value only.

Comment: I did what i could but its already a day i could not solve it. can you edit it on my above code,please?